# AppleScript, read / write data from file (config file for script)

Tags: applescript

I'm creating a Boot script that will be run on several computers in several different locations.
This script will sync fonts, connect to SMB shares, and more.

The different locations operates with different IPs, folder structures etc. So I'd like my script
to read and write to a custom config file, that I will store on each location.

How can I read and write variables from an external file?

Examples of some variables that I need to read and write.

```
Raidfolder: Volumes/QNAP-RAID/FILES #POSIX path
RaidSYM: ~/Desktop/RAID
Mount: user:password@192.168.0.10
```

Is there an clever way to read info from "Raidfolder" and use that as an variable in the script.
I also want to store some user selected folders witch the script will ask for on first time run

```
choose folder with prompt "Please choose a folder:" default location alias PrTemplates
```

I did, manage write properties to a .sctp, but got an unicode text error from the POSIX path,
also I'd prefer to have the config in clear text format, so it can be edited in texteditor.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks John Iver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AppleScript, read / write data from file (config file for script)

Have a look at [Working with Property List Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WorkwithPropertyListFiles.html), which is the way I'd go.

---

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** and worked without issues as is and shows how to create the **~/Desktop/Example.plist** *file* and read it back. The two `log ...` lines are just to show in the **Replies** *pane* that the *variables* have been set to a different *value* prior to being read back from the **~/Desktop/Example.plist** *file*.

```applescript
set RaidFolder to "/Volumes/QNAP-RAID/FILES"
set RaidSYM to "~/Desktop/RAID"
set Mount to "user:password@192.168.0.10"

tell application "System Events"
    
    set theParentDictionary to ¬
        make new property list item with properties {kind:record}
    
    set thePropertyListFilePath to "~/Desktop/Example.plist"
    
    set thePropertyListFile to ¬
        make new property list file with properties ¬
            {contents:theParentDictionary, name:thePropertyListFilePath}
    
    tell property list items of thePropertyListFile
        make new property list item at end with properties ¬
            {kind:string, name:"RaidFolder", value:RaidFolder}
        make new property list item at end with properties ¬
            {kind:string, name:"RaidSYM", value:RaidSYM}
        make new property list item at end with properties ¬
            {kind:string, name:"Mount", value:Mount}
    end tell
    
end tell

set RaidFolder to missing value
set RaidSYM to missing value
set Mount to missing value

log RaidFolder & linefeed & RaidSYM & linefeed & Mount

tell application "System Events"
    tell property list file thePropertyListFilePath
        set RaidFolder to value of property list item "RaidFolder"
        set RaidSYM to value of property list item "RaidSYM"
        set Mount to value of property list item "Mount"
    end tell
end tell

log RaidFolder & linefeed & RaidSYM & linefeed & Mount
```

The example **XML Plist** *file* shows what was created as the **~/Example.plist** *file*.  It's a *structured* **ACSII Text** *file* and can be edited in any **text editor**.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Mount</key>
    <string>user:password@192.168.0.10</string>
    <key>RaidFolder</key>
    <string>/Volumes/QNAP-RAID/FILES</string>
    <key>RaidSYM</key>
    <string>~/Desktop/RAID</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

If you want to go with a *plain* **ACSII Text** *file*, instead of something *structured* like the **XML Plist** *file*, then have a look at: [Reading and Writing Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html)

---

**Notes:**

- RE: "Mount: user:password@192.168.0.10" -- Not a wise idea to store *user name* and *password* in a plain text *file*.

Comment: This is perfect! This helps a lot! Simple and works flawless. Thank you. Now I also learnt about the log feature, handy.